# Use UPDATE query inside SELECT query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to get shareholders current balance from table, then add for example, 10 percent to their current balance and then update the table back with the new balance, but i am getting error that says there is a connection not closed.

UPDATE: profit_percentage is a variable provided by the user.

```
try
{
    var con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    string stm = "SELECT * From shareholders_term";

    var cmd = new SqlCommand(stm, con);

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        if (rdr["current_balance"] != null)
        {
            num++;

            int current_shareholder = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["shareholder_id"]);
            current_balance = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr["current_balance"]);

            decimal percentage = current_balance * profitpercentage / 100;
            decimal new_balance = percentage + current_balance;

            var cmdcurrentbalance = new SqlCommand(
                "UPDATE shareholders_term SET profit_percentage = @percentage, current_balance = @new_balance WHERE shareholder_id = @current_shareholder",
                con
            );

            cmdcurrentbalance.Parameters.AddWithValue("@percentage", profitpercentage);
            cmdcurrentbalance.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_balance", new_balance);
            cmdcurrentbalance.Parameters.AddWithValue("@current_shareholder", current_shareholder);

            cmdcurrentbalance.ExecuteNonQuery();

            lblupdatecounter.Text = num + " - Shareholders updated.";
        }
    }
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Profit added to shareholders");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Why update each shareholder one at a time? If you want to update them all, why not you just do that?

Comment: Can I suggest you align you code with the left hand side of the screen and remove all the empty lines. Its very hard to read as it is.

Comment: Some tips: 1- You would likely want `... from shareholders_term where not current_balance is null` 2- You can do all the calculations and update all the rows in just one update command. 3- The ExecuteNonQuery return the number of rows affected.

Comment: The simplest fix is probably to run the select query first and store the column values that you need from that in a memory table of some sort, and then iterate over that to do the updates.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError in fact that SELECT statement is not even needed

Comment: Unless you have MARS set, you will not succeed reusing connection while reading from it.

Comment: Why are people still writing inline SQL in 2024 instead of using ORMs?

Comment: Oh and don't use [addwithvalue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @IanKemp at least he's not concating SQL from raw input values like it's 1999

Comment: @siggemannen oh yay, how far we have progressed /s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will easily fit as a single `UPDATE` query, with no need to ever pull any data back to C# for processing.

I don't see a source for the `profitpercentage` variable in C#. I expect this was intended to load from the table in the same way as `current_balance`. If that's true, the result will look like this:

```
string sql = @"
 UPDATE shareholders_term 
 SET current_balance = current_balance * (100.0 + profit_percentage) / 100.0,
     profit_percentage = current_balance * profit_percentage / 100.0
 WHERE current_balance IS NOT NULL;
";

try
{   
    using var con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    
    con.Open();
    var num = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    lblupdatecounter.Text = $"{num} - Shareholders updated."
    MessageBox.Show("Profit added to shareholders");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Though I also question the logic here: it seems to go back and forth between treating `profit_percentage` as a value or a percentage.

Comment: imho profit percentage is likely not in the column data but an external variable, but not enough data in the question about it so...